# Oracle - insert select max where not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write something like below.

The objective is not to have more than one record with the same description. We have the unique constraint on the description column.

I must write this insert query that should work (without throwing errors) even if it gets executed more than once accidentally. Column **id** is the primary key of the table

```
insert into test (id, description)
select max(id)+1, 'test record' from test
where not exists ( select 1 from test where description = 'test record' );
```

if there is already a record in test table with description = 'test record', then the result of the following query has null for the id, and the insert fails with primary key violation

```
select max(id)+1, 'test record' from test
where not exists ( select 1 from test where description = 'test record' );
```

if i have to alternately write sql block with variable and begin/end to accomplish this, i am good to do that
however, any advice is appreciated

Comment: So if a record with description `'test record'` already exists in the table, do you want to insert a new record or not?

Comment: sorry for not being clear; if a record with description 'test record' already exist,we do not want to insert, and we do not want errors thrown.

Comment: As `id` is the primary key, this will result in an error if executed concurrently. Why don't you use a sequence to generate the `ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the select statement inside another query, like this:

```
insert into test (id, description)
select t.id, t.description
from (
  select max(id)+1 as id, 'test record' as description
  from test
  where not exists (select 1 from test where description = 'test record' )
) t
where t.id is not null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f7162f4e42737528981d0176a5b52787).

Answer (score 1):

The use of an aggregate function without a `group by` clause forces the query to generate a record even when the `where` clause eliminates all rows

A quick workaround would be add a (dummy) `group by` clause:

```
insert into test (id, description)
select max(id)+1, 'test record' from test
where not exists ( select 1 from test where description = 'test record' )
group by 2;
```

Or alternatively, you can move the aggregate function to a subquery. I find that this solution makes the intent clearer:

```
insert into test (id, description)
select t.id, 'test record' 
from (select max(id) + 1  id from test) t
where not exists ( select 1 from test where description = 'test record');
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dcaa9f4d23be3b5bc50a9eb2da164859)**